# Disable views on GitLens in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

GitLens is a wonderful extension for working with git on VScode.
However, most of the "views" are just there in your face. For example, Tags, Remotes view.

Is there a way to disable selected Gitlens views in VScode? I have spent considerable time to find this out but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to disable the views in the source control view.

[image]